# How can i attach a debugger to google v8?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, v8

In my application (Windows 10 VC2017) i enabled the possibility to write and execute scripts using [google v8](https://v8.dev/) and [v8pp](https://github.com/pmed/v8pp).

v8pp calls a script like this:

```
v8::Local<v8::Value> context::run_script(std::string const& source, std::string const& filename)
{
    v8::EscapableHandleScope scope(isolate_);
v8::Local<v8::Context> context = isolate_->GetCurrentContext();

v8::ScriptOrigin origin(to_v8(isolate_, filename));
v8::Local<v8::Script> script;
bool const is_valid = v8::Script::Compile(context,
    to_v8(isolate_, source), &origin).ToLocal(&script);

v8::Local<v8::Value> result;
if (!script.IsEmpty())
{
    auto res1 = script->Run(context); // 
    if(! res1.IsEmpty())
         result = res1.ToLocalChecked();
    }
    return scope.Escape(result);
}
```

How can i attach a debugger (chrome debug) to my code?

I found googles description at https://v8.dev/docs/inspector -
But this leaves some things blank and consists mostly of js code?

And i found the implementation for v8toolkit at https://github.com/xaxxon/v8toolkit/blob/master/src/debugger.cpp. But this seems to run not for windows.

What is a easy way to attach chrome debug to js code? The code is typically not a file but rather is stored in a data base and then stored in a std::string.

Comment: Try this article from Microsoft https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging

Answer (score 1):

I finally got done a windows version of v8inspector that works well with my stand alone windows application with integrated v8.

I made a own fork including descriptions where to find/build the required 3rd party libraries (or where to find prebuilds). I also did a number of changes/additions:
https://github.com/StefanWoe/v8inspector

In the meanwhile this has also been merged into the parent project:
https://github.com/hsharsha/v8inspector

EDIT:
In the meanwhile ive been pointed to another implementation built with boost::beast and no other dependencies. Much simpler and more robust etc.:
https://github.com/ahmadov/v8_inspector_example